# Plotting with legend label

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

I am plotting 4 data files in one plot like this :

```
 Legended[ListLinePlot[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.0, 1.0}, {0, 1.3}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, Bold], 
  ImageSize -> 550, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[None]}, {Blue, Dashing[None]}, {Red, 
     Dashing[Tiny]}, {Blue, Dashing[Tiny]}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["v", 20, Bold, Black], 
    Style["d\[Phi]/dv", 20, Bold, Black]}, AspectRatio -> 2/3], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[{Red, Dashing[None]}], 
    Directive[{Blue, Dashing[None]}], Directive[{Red, Dashing[Tiny]}],
     Directive[{Blue, 
      Dashing[Tiny]}]}, {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(e\)]\)(\!\(\
\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Theta]\), \
\(14\)]\)=0.1)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(_\)], \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.1)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.01)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(_\)], \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.01)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]], {0.3, 
   0.7}]]
```

and the plot look like this :

[image]

Now what I want is to add a specific legend label for solid lines and another label for dashed lines on the top of the current legends. How to do that?

Comment: You do not accept answers. All submitted answers have checkmarks next to them and you can select  only one of these. Upon selection, the checkmark will turn green. In addition, you can upvote answers as well. Search engines prioritize pages with accepted answers. It is also the accepted way to say "Thanks" on all SE sites.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1];
data = Map[SortBy[First]]@RandomReal[1.2, {4, 20, 2}]; 

plotstyles = Directive @@@ Tuples[{Dashing /@ {None, Tiny}, {Red, Blue}}];

options = {PlotRange -> {{-1, 1.3}, {0, 1.3}}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   Axes -> False, 
   FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, Bold], 
   ImageSize -> 550, 
   PlotStyle -> plotstyles, 
   FrameLabel -> {Style["v", 20, Bold, Black], Style["dϕ/dv", 20, Bold, Black]}, 
   AspectRatio -> 2/3};

legendLabels = MapApply[ToString[
      Subscript[#2 @ ν, e][Superscript[sin, 2][2 Subscript[θ, 14]] == #], 
      TraditionalForm] &] @
   Tuples[{ {0.1, 0.01}, {Identity, OverBar}}];
```

With these definitions, we can produce an output similar to the one in OP:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[data, Evaluate @ options];

linelegend = LineLegend[plotstyles, legendLabels, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]];

Legended[llp, Placed[linelegend, {0.3, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

Two functions to modify legend layout and legend labels:

```
ClearAll[groupLegends, modifyLabels]

groupLegends[groupsizes_, grouplabels_] := Append[LegendLayout -> 
  (Grid[Join @@ MapThread[Prepend] @
    {TakeList[#, groupsizes], {#, SpanFromLeft} & /@ grouplabels},
   Alignment -> {Left, Center}] &)];

modifyLabels[newlabels_] := ReplacePart[#, {2} -> newlabels] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
groupSizes = {2, 2};

groupLabels = Style[#, 20] & /@ (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ 
     DeleteDuplicates[# & @@@ ToExpression @ legendLabels]);

newLegendLabels = Map[ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &] @ 
   Map[Head] @ ToExpression @ legendLabels;

modifyLabels[newLegendLabels] @ 
 groupLegends[groupSizes, groupLabels] @ 
  linelegend
```

[image]

```
Legended[llp, 
 Placed[
   modifyLabels[newLegendLabels] @
    groupLegends[groupSizes, groupLabels] @ linelegend,
  {0.3, 0.7}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
Legended[
 ListLinePlot[{p1, p2, p3, p4}, PlotRange -> {{-1.0, 1.0}, {0, 1.3}}, 
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 20, Bold], 
  ImageSize -> 550, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[None]}, {Blue, Dashing[None]}, {Red, 
     Dashing[Tiny]}, {Blue, Dashing[Tiny]}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Style["v", 20, Bold, Black], 
    Style["d\[Phi]/dv", 20, Bold, Black]}, AspectRatio -> 2/3], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[{Black, Dashing[None]}], 
    Directive[{Black, Dashing[Tiny]}], 
    Directive[{Black, Dashing[Tiny]}], 
    Directive[{Red, Dashing[None]}], Directive[{Blue, Dashing[None]}],
     Directive[{Red, Dashing[Tiny]}], 
    Directive[{Blue, Dashing[Tiny]}]}, {"No dashing", "Dashing", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.1)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(_\)], \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.1)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.01)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[OverscriptBox[\(\[Nu]\), \(_\)], \
\(e\)]\)(\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Sin\), \(2\)]\)2\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(\[Theta]\), \(14\)]\)=0.01)"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[18]], {0.3, 
   0.6}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Actually what I want is like a heading "sin^2 2 \theta_14 = 0.1" under which it will show two solid lines, one for \nu_e and other for \bar \nu_e. Then again a heading as "sin^2 2 \theta_14 = 0.01" under which it will show two dashed lines, one for \nu_e and other for \bar \nu_e .

Comment: Basically i don't want to write "sin^2 2 \theta_14" again and again. I am finding a way to do that.